# Ionic <input type="file"> not working in ios 10.0.2 and above!! app crashes

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

My app is build in phonegap and trying to upload file  but app crashes.

Comment: use https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer for file transfer.

Comment: Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46540140/ionic-android-when-choose-image-from-gallery-the-app-crash