# ionic android : when choose image from gallery the app crash

Tags: android, angularjs, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

When I click on `choose file(input="file")` to choose an image from gallery , after select the image on android the app crash , and also on ios (iphone).
I already add the permissions on the androidmanifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

and still not working.

Comment: Post crash stack trace pls

Comment: there's no stack trace because the app crashed , and i don;t know how to see it on android studio + i don't have android studio on my machine

Comment: Did you try to use a cordova plugin to access the gallery? This is the one exposed by Ionic Native https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/photo-library/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was getting the same issue in iOS.
Try adding these data to info.plist

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires access to the photo library.</string>
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires access to the camera.</string>
```

For android can you share the logcat output.

1. How are you building the app, if you don't have Android Studio? Are you using phonegap?
2. If you have Android Studio, then a tool **Monitor** is pre installed with Android Studio. When you open Monitor, then the logs for the app can be seen

If phonegap is used, can u share the id, I can take a look if you want

Comment: i see the logcat via sdk tools monitor.bat : but i can't copy the text log

Comment: i'm using ionic cordova build android  (command line to build the project)

Comment: You could select all the items (Ctrl + A), then save the data using the Save Icon (Floppy Icon)

Comment: You can paste the output here

Comment: too long , can't support all the text output

Comment: can you join this chatroom https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/155816/tanansatpal?tab=general

Comment: i tried to access the link but no chat room provided.
and i  think i fixed the problem on android by adding :
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Answer (score 0):

If you only targeting images, I suggest to use the Cordova / Ionic Native plugins instead of using the file input. It will be easier and you will get more control in accessing images and its properties.
You can use either [Camera plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera) or [Photo Library Plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/photo-library/). You can use the `requestAuthorization` function to request the permissions from the user.

You may need to add permissions inside your config.xml. For example, as mentioned in the Camera Plugin Ionic's page

> [Warning] Since IOS 10 the camera requires permissions to be placed in your config.xml add

```
<config-file parent="NSCameraUsageDescription" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist"><string>You can take photos</string></config-file>
```

Please note that it is always the best idea to have all the permissions inside your config.xml file and not in the AndroidManifest.xml / info.plist, as it will always be added automatically once you add / run your build on the native platforms.